# PHP BASE64 to Image convert

Tags: php

base64 is of jpeg. below is my given PHP:

```
$img['img'] = 'img1.png';
$filedata = explode(',', $this->input->post('lostimage1'));
write_file('./uploads/'.$data['pet_hidenum'].'/'.$img['img'], $filedata[1]);
```

How can I determine whether given base64 is of jpeg or png? My code is working fine but I just want to know base64 string is jpeg or png

Answer (score 0):

```
$imagedata = base64_decode("****");
$file = finfo_open();
$mime_type = finfo_buffer($file, $imagedata, FINFO_MIME_TYPE);
```

Please refer to this [link.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the base64 code into PHP's mime_content_type function.

```
<?php
    // Will retrun as image/jpg or image/png depending on the type
    $fileType = mime_content_type("base64codegoeshere");
?>
```

Comment: Please help me aHow to run mime_content_type function in CodeIgniter